# Seeking tool to create an empty column in a CSV file and a columns with a fixed value

Tags: csv

I need regularly to create a new CSV file based on taking columns from another CSV file.

This involves:

- Select specific columns from the source CSV file in specific order

  - Column 2 is column 3 of the source file
  - Column 3 is column 2 of the source file
  - Column 5 is column 18 of the source file
  - and a few more columns in a similar way
- Set all cells in column 1 to have the fixed value "MS", Column header to be "Title"
- Set all cells in column 4 to be empty. Column header to be "Date Set"

I can see how to select specific columns using [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)(using Python), but found no tools with an easy way to set the cell values on the other two columns I need.

This could be done in Excel, but are there any tools which would make the whole process easy to run regularly?

Comment: Easiest way I would do it, is to write a Python script using the `pandas` library. So read the original csv file as dataframe, make changes, and write dataframe to new output. It's relatively straightforward, but if you're not familiar with Python programming just ask someone to write it for you. Also, check out this question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/51276232/1745616

Comment: You could also use Excel VBA and create a macro that reads the original CSV and then it only writes the desired columns to a new sheet, see code example in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58867643/1745616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/). In example starting from this CSV

```
data,stato,codice_regione
1,ITA,08
2,ITA,08
3,ITA,08
```

you can run

```
mlr --csv cut -f data,stato then put -S '$Title="MS";${Date Set}=""' then reorder -f Title,data,"Date Set",stato input.csv >output.csv
```

to have

```
Title,data,Date Set,stato
MS,1,,ITA
MS,2,,ITA
MS,3,,ITA
```

Some notes:

- `cut` to choose the field you want extract from the source;
- `put` to create the 2 new fields;
- `reorder` to set the fields order

Comment: Thanks, this is an amazing solution. I've looked further into Miller, which also allows me to rename columns, which is another feature I wanted. I'll certainly be using it again. The new versions 6, currently in beta, has a WIndows executable, so is very easy to implement.